# LINQ complex search query advice

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help with some LINQ logic that I am trying to do

Using EF, I have this result set:

[image]

Basically what I want to achieve is if the user wants to find an element that has TagID 3 AND TagID 4 it should only return `Low, Medium`

This should ignore `Low` as this element doesn't have TagID 4

Also if the user just wants the elements that contain TagID 3, it should return `Low, Medium` and `Low` as both contain TagID  3

I have tried this just to get `Low, Medium` back (the harder logic) but to no prevail.

```
var result = result.Where(x => x.TagID == 3 && x.TagID == 4).ToList();
```

A step in the right direction is all that is needed please

Comment: `x.TagID == 3 && x.TagID == 4` this will never evaluate to true since the items are associated to only 1 TagID

Comment: @vc74 indeed. Because they are separate elements.

Comment: But `x` refers to a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if tags are only available once per ID (i.e. no items with the same ID and the same tag ID).

I don't think EF will be available to translate to SQL -> materialize first.

```
var q = result.ToList();

var tagIDs = new HashSet<int>() { 3, 4 };

IEnumerable<string> itemContents = 
    q.Where(x => tagIDs.Contains(x.TagID)). // Keep only the tags we're interested in
      GroupBy(x => x.Id). // Group the items by ID
      Where(g => (g.Count() == tagIDs.Count)). // Select the groups having the right number of items
      SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => x.ItemContent)). // Extract ItemContent
      Distinct(); // Remove duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if EF this swallows, here is an example:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { Id = 12, TagID = 3, ItemContent = "Low" },
    new { Id = 13, TagID = 3, ItemContent = "Low, Medium" },
    new { Id = 13, TagID = 4, ItemContent = "Low, Medium" },
};

var search = new List<int>(new[] { 3, 4 });

var result = data
    // group the items on ItemContent
    .GroupBy(item => item.ItemContent, d => d, (k, g) => new { ItemContent = k, g })
    // only select groups when all searchitems are found in a list of TagID
    .Where(groupedItem => search.All(i => groupedItem.g.Select(y => y.TagID).Contains(i)))
    // select the result
    .Select(groupedItem => groupedItem);


foreach (var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r.ItemContent);

Console.ReadLine();
```